# Which of these Python 2.7 libraries can I remove without bricking my 16.04?

Tags: apt, python, uninstall, python-2.7

I am trying to remove all non-system Python 2.7 libraries which I installed in my 16.04. I want to reset my Python library list to its default.

I have manually removed most of the libraries myself but still have more than 200 libraries left. From the below list, I am really not sure which is a system library and which is not.

This is the list I got using `pip freeze | grep -v "^-e"`:

```
absl-py==0.6.1
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
alabaster==0.7.10
ann-visualizer==2.4
appdirs==1.4.3
argh==0.26.2
args==0.1.0
asn1crypto==0.23.0
astor==0.7.1
astroid==1.4.9
atari-py==0.0.18
attrs==17.2.0
autopep8==1.3.2
Babel==2.4.0
backports-abc==0.4
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.3
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
backports.tempfile==1.0rc1
backports.weakref==1.0rc1
bcrypt==3.1.3
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
bleach==3.1.0
blinker==1.3
brewer2mpl==1.4.1
bs4==0.0.1
ccsm==0.9.12.3
certifi==2018.1.18
cffi==1.11.0
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
clint==0.5.1
cloudpickle==0.5.5
cma==2.5.3
cmarkgfm==0.4.2
colorama==0.3.9
configparser==3.5.0
contextlib2==0.5.5
convnetskeras==0.1
cryptography==2.2.1
cssselect==0.9.1
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.25.2
dask==0.19.1
db.py==0.5.3
debtags==2.0
decorator==4.0.11
defer==1.0.6
dirspec==13.10
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.13.1
duplicity==0.7.6
EasyProcess==0.2.3
entrypoints==0.2.2
enum==0.4.6
enum34==1.1.6
ffn==0.1.12
flake8==3.5.0
funcsigs==1.0.2
functools32==3.2.3.post2
future==0.16.0
futures==3.2.0
gast==0.2.0
ggplot==0.11.2
gitdb2==2.0.2
GitPython==2.1.5
gmpy==1.17
gmpy2==2.0.7
gnureadline==6.3.3
goose-extractor==1.0.25
graphviz==0.5.2
grpcio==1.17.0
gyp==0.1
html5lib==1.0.1
httpbl==1.0.1
httplib2==0.9.1
idna==2.6
imagesize==0.7.1
impacket==0.9.12
inflection==0.3.1
ipaddress==1.0.18
ipykernel==4.3.1
ipython==5.0.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.1.2
isort==4.2.5
itsdangerous==0.24
jedi==0.10.2
jieba==0.35
Jinja2==2.8
jiphy==1.2.1
jsondatabase==0.1.7
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter-client==5.2.3
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
jupyterlab-launcher==0.10.5
keyring==9.0
kiwisolver==1.0.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.2.2
lockfile==0.12.2
lxml==4.1.1
Markdown==2.6.11
MarkupSafe==0.23
marshmallow==2.15.0
MAT==0.6.1
matplotlib==2.2.3
maxminddb==1.4.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mechanize==0.2.5
mido==1.2.3
mistune==0.7.3
mock==2.0.0
more-itertools==2.2
mutagen==1.31
nbconvert==5.1.1
nbformat==4.3.0
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.2
netifaces==0.10.4
networkx==1.11
nose==1.3.7
notebook==5.4.1
numexpr==2.6.1
numpy==1.11.0
oauth2client==4.0.0
oauthlib==2.0.1
obfsproxy==0.2.13
oneconf==0.3.9
packaging==16.8
PAM==0.4.2
pandocfilters==1.4.1
paramiko==2.3.1
parsel==1.2.0
pathlib2==2.3.0
pathtools==0.1.2
patsy==0.4.1
pbr==3.0.0
pcapy==0.10.8
pdfrw==0.2
pep8==1.7.0
pexpect==4.2.1
phe==1.3.0
pickleshare==0.7.3
Pillow==5.2.0
piston-mini-client==0.7.5
pkginfo==1.4.2
plotly==2.0.7
ply==3.10
pocketsphinx==0.1.3
prettytable==0.7.2
prompt-toolkit==1.0.3
protobuf==3.6.1
psutil==5.2.1
ptyprocess==0.5.2
pyasn1==0.1.9
pyasn1-modules==0.0.8
PyAudio==0.2.11
pybars3==0.9.3
pycairo==1.18.0
pycodestyle==2.3.1
pycparser==2.18
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycryptodome==3.4.7
pycryptodomex==3.6.6
pycups==1.9.73
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
pydot==1.2.2
pydot2==1.0.33
pyflakes==1.5.0
pygame===1.9.1release
pyglet==1.2.4
Pygments==2.2.0
pygobject==3.20.0
PyInstaller==3.2
PyJWT==1.7.1
pylint==1.6.5
PyMeta3==0.5.1
pymongo==3.4.0
PyNaCl==1.1.2
PyOpenGL==3.1.0
pyOpenSSL==17.5.0
pypandoc==1.3.3
pyparsing==2.2.0
PyPDF2==1.26.0
PyPrind==2.9.9
pyptlib==0.0.6
pyserial==3.0.1
pysmi==0.1.3
pysnmp==4.4.6
PySocks==1.6.8
Pyste==0.9.10
python-apt==1.1.0b1+ubuntu0.16.4.3
python-augeas==0.5.0
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-debian==0.1.27
python-docx==0.8.7
python-gflags==3.1.1
python-nmap==0.6.1
pytz==2018.3
PyWavelets==1.0.0
pyxdg==0.25
PyYAML==3.12
pyzmq==15.3.0
QtAwesome==0.4.4
qtconsole==4.2.1
QtPy==1.2.1
queuelib==1.4.2
raven==6.6.0
readme-renderer==22.0
requests==2.18.4
requests-file==1.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
retrying==1.3.3
rope==0.10.5
rpy2==2.8.3
rsa==3.4.2
scandir==1.7
Send2Trash==1.5.0
service-identity==17.0.0
sh==1.12.14
shortuuid==0.5.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
simplejson==3.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.11.0
smmap2==2.0.3
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
software-center-aptd-plugins==0.0.0
SpeechRecognition==3.7.1
Sphinx==1.5.3
stevedore==1.30.0
subprocess32==3.2.7
tables==3.2.3.1
tabulate==0.8.2
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.1
testpath==0.3
tldextract==1.5.1
toolz==0.9.0
tornado==4.4
tqdm==4.27.0
traitlets==4.3.2
twine==1.12.1
Twisted==16.0.0
ubuntuone-client-data==14.4
unity-lens-photos==1.0
update-checker==0.16
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.22
virtualenv==15.1.0
virtualenv-clone==0.4.0
virtualenvwrapper==4.8.2
w3lib==1.17.0
watchdog==0.8.3
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.12.1
widgetsnbextension==3.1.4
wrapt==1.10.10
ws4py==0.5.1
xdot==0.6
zope.interface==4.1.3
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not know about a direct method. Regarding the packages installed trough APT, you could list the packages with

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep python
```

and remove them carefully. You will get asked to confirm the removal of dependencies. Of course you'll refrain from removing anything pulling the package Python out altogether.

Regarding the packages installed through pip, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24736563/3081478 may give you some hints.

Taking another approach, you could spin up a fresh 16.04 VM, run `pip freeze | grep -v "^-e"` and diff it with your current one.